# Printing the Barcode font using radprintdocument control in c#

Tags: c#, barcode, radgridview, rad-controls

I have a radgridview in which I am displaying my data. My radgridview columns have different fonts. One column is simple but the other has BarCode font. Now I want to print that radgridview But when I click on the Print it is not showing the Barcode format in the file its generating whether its a pdf format or xps. How can I do that?

[image]

The Printer generated file looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole font changes when you save as pdf. BTW what are you using to print? And what do you want to print exactly? if you want to print the grid you can always try something like this [Print Panel in Windows Form C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605840/print-panel-in-windows-form-c-sharp) If you want something more professional try using a real report like a crystal report where you can print barcodes very easily.

Comment: I am using radPrintDocument control to Print the radgridview. I am doing it like this radPrintDocument1.AssociatedObject = radgridview1; radPrintDocument1.Print();