# Create Image with high resolution and print using ZPL command

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing, zpl-ii

I'm trying to create a image that include my label info, then by using GF command to print image. My label dimension is 80x37 mm (w x h) and my printer is ZT610 600dpi, i need to create a image with 80x37mm of dimension with 1890x874 pixel image resolution. (Printer Formula: 1mm = 600dpi/25.4 -> 80x37mm = 1890x874)

My idea is create a panel, write info into it then save as png/jpeg. I'm folowing the formula to create panel 1 mm = 3.7795275591 pixel. So i create the panel with 302x
140pixel.But when i save the image as 1890x874 pixel then print it, the printing is blurred

My question is: Can i create a image with 80x37mm and high resolution (1890x874pixel)?
Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: Why don't you create a proper label with ZPL? There should be some libs around for that in C#.

Comment: Create a proper label with ZPL? i don't really understand what your mean? Which C# libs i need to find for that?

Comment: There are many ZPL commands for text, primitive graphics and images. You could add an image of your desired result to your question for further assistence. Please use Google for finding a ZPL lib that fits your needs.

Comment: [Here's an answer of how to print a panel to the printer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10640745/3585500) Why not install the Zebra printer and let the zebra print driver handle the ZPL translation?